# Probability each player wins largest number, given each player has a weight and draws a random number

Tags: probability

### Context

In my game, there are mites with special abilities. All mites found in the wild start out as "Plain" mites. Plain mites can be converted into special mites by feeding them certain materials. But some mites can only be obtained by breeding certain types of mites together.

In this scenario, the player is breeding a Fire mite with a Coal mite to hopefully get a Diamond mite. When two mites breed, the offspring can:

- inherit one of the parent’s types (Fire or Coal)
- inherit neither and just become a Plain mite
- inherit an available combination of the parent’s types (in this case, Diamond)

So, in this case, there are four candidates for the offspring’s type. But each one is assigned a hard-coded weight:

- Plain: 10
- Diamond: 22
- Coal: 17
- Fire: 20

To determine the offspring’s type, the game performs a single cycle of the following steps:

1. For each candidate, generate an individual random number between 0 and 100 (inclusive)
2. Each candidate divides their random number by their weight
3. The resulting quotient is the score

The candidate with the highest score wins and becomes the offspring’s type. This means that the lower the weight, the higher chance a type will be inherited.

My question is, **is it possible to calculate the probability each candidate will win?** If so, what math concepts are involved so I can read further?

### Actual Results

I simulated 5,000 cycles of the above process with the same candidates. The following output gives me the actual results:

```
Average Roll: 50.12/100: Plain: 3107 (62%); Diamond: 362 (7%); Coal: 978 (20%); Fire: 553 (11%)
```

### My Attempt

Since the average random number is 50, I thought I should calculate step 1 of the algorithm assuming the random number is 50:

```
f(score) = (random_number) / (weight)
```

This gives us each candidate’s score on average:

- Plain: 5
- Diamond: 2.27
- Coal: 2.94
- Fire: 2.5

Then, to calculate each probability, I divided each score by the sum of scores:

```
f(final_score) = (this_score) / (sum_of_all_scores)
```

Then we have each candidate’s probabilities:

- Plain: 39.3%
- Diamond: 17.9%
- Coal: 23.1%
- Fire: 19.7%

These results are nowhere near the actual data. I went wrong somewhere.

### Isolated Simulation in Python

I used the following Python script to simulate this event:

````
import random

candidates = {
    'Plain': {'Weight': 10, 'Wins': 0, 'Ratio': 0},
    'Diamond': {'Weight': 22, 'Wins': 0, 'Ratio': 0},
    'Coal': {'Weight': 17, 'Wins': 0, 'Ratio': 0},
    'Fire': {'Weight': 20, 'Wins': 0, 'Ratio': 0}
}

results = {
    'Plain': 0,
    'Diamond': 0,
    'Coal': 0,
    'Fire': 0
}

rounds = 0
rolls = 0
sum_of_rolls = 0

for i in range(5000):
    for candidate in candidates:
        roll = random.randint(0, 100)
        rolls += 1
        sum_of_rolls += roll
        candidates[candidate]['Quotient'] = roll / candidates[candidate]['Weight']
        results[candidate] = candidates[candidate]['Quotient']
    rounds += 1
    winner = max(results, key=results.get)
    candidates[winner]['Wins'] += 1
    for candidate in candidates:
        candidates[candidate]['Ratio'] = '{:.0%}'.format(candidates[candidate]['Wins'] / rounds)
    average_roll = sum_of_rolls / rolls
    print(f'Session {rounds}, Average Roll:{round(average_roll, 2)}/100: Plain: {candidates["Plain"]["Wins"]} ({candidates["Plain"]["Ratio"]}); Diamond: {candidates["Diamond"]["Wins"]} ({candidates["Diamond"]["Ratio"]}); Coal: {candidates["Coal"]["Wins"]} ({candidates["Coal"]["Ratio"]}); Fire: {candidates["Fire"]["Wins"]} ({candidates["Fire"]["Ratio"]})')
```
````

Comment: This is hard to follow.  How are "types" decided?  Does every player have a unique type (however decided)?  If so, then I'd really expect the player with the lowest weight to have a huge advantage.  But why would you sum the quotients?  What does that represent?  And what are you simulating?

Comment: Hmm maybe I'm missing something and apologies if so, but are you just trying to get particular breeding probabilities for each outcome? (plain, crystal, coal, fire). 

If that's the case, why not just use `random.choices` from the Python standard library or something like this, with the desired weights supplied? I don't quite understand what you're trying to do with the quotient sum.

Comment: @lulu Types are decided either by inheritance or converting (a mechanic that's not relevant here). You are right, types with the lowest weight have an advantage, but my question is how do I calculate the probability each type will have the largest number? So I can adjust the weights to balance the game.

Comment: Still not clear.  Are we to assume that there is one player of each type?  Something else?  As is common in game design, the details really matter.  Small changes in the rule set can have big impacts.

Comment: All that said, given a clear set of rules, simulation really might be the best way to go.  Sure, it's possible to get these numbers exactly, but do you really need that?  The simulations let you change the numbers (and even the rules) on the fly, and you don't want to have to repeat a lengthy computation for every such change.

Comment: @lulu Sorry for not being clear. A "plain" type is the default, but it can be converted by feeding it elements. But some types, like Crystal, can only be obtained by breeding a Coal with a Fire. When two types breed, the offspring can either (1) inherit one of its parents' types, (2) inherit neither and just be a plain with no type, or (3) a combination of the parents' types, if available. There may not be a solution and running simulations might be all I can do, but I would love to understand the math concepts involved, if there is a solution.

Comment: @miradulo Yes, just trying to get each outcome's probability. The quotient sum was my attempt at a _combinations with replacements_ solution, but failing because I don't understand what I'm doing. I could do simulations, but if there is a solution, I wanted to know what math concepts I could study up so I can solve simular problems in the future. Understanding the math would also allow me to make a spreadsheet formula so I could adjust values and see probabilities in real-time.